# Access an instance from Terminal

Tags: python, class, module, instance, interactive

Can't figure this out. In Terminal, I import a module which instantiates a class, which I haven't figured out how to access. Of course, I can always instantiate in Terminal:

```
Server=Data.ServerData()
```

Then I can get a result:

```
Server.Property().DefaultChart
```

However, I want to skip that step getting the result directly from the instance already running in the module. I think Data.Server in this case should load the Server instance from when I imported Data:

```
Data.Server.Property().DefaultChart

>>> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Server'
```

So how to access the running instance from Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If importing `Data.py` implicitly creates an instance of the `Data.ServerData` class (somewhat dubious, but OK in certain cases), that still tells us nothing about how that module chose to name that one instance.  Do `dir(Data)` at the `>>>` prompt to see all the names defined in the `Data` module; if you want to see what names (if any!) have values that are instances of `Data.ServerData`, e.g.:

```
>>> [n for n in dir(Data) if isinstance(getattr(Data,n), Data.ServerData)]
```

Reading `Data.py`'s source code might be simpler, but you do have many other options for such introspection to find out exactly what's going on (and how it differ from what you EXPECTED [[not sure on what basis!]] to be going on).

Comment: Thanks, such a n00b! I had instantiated inside a
if __name__=="__main__":
wrapper, which is why it worked in a browser but not in Terminal.
Those are good diagnostic tools.